# Can I Manage User Roles In just JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, frontend

hi everyone :) I'm currently a front-end beginner and I'm wondering if I could manage users authorities by JavaScript code alone?
I want to create a simple Student Management System with Log in Features, with admin who have the full authority to manage the students data (add, delete, update)& other users can only log in and read.
it that possible in the Clint-side? or it's server-side only?

Comment: Everybody will be able to change front-end code and access restricted data in this way

Comment: JavaScript isn't just a frontend language, you can do all of this in JavaScript if that's what you're familiar with; you will need to use a JavaScript backend such as Express.

Comment: If you manage authorization on "client-side" then anyone can inject js and become and admin easily. Always do this on the server side.

Comment: Yeah, authorization and authority management should be done server side because data scope changes as authority increased and if you try doing it client side then you will have to send full data with risk of anyone reading it

Comment: it's just school project nothing serous & well only seen by the teacher

Comment: There's no point in doing school projects incorrectly. Suppose you're in a culinary school and you prepare a dish that looks bad and tastes awfully and your excuse is that it's just to show it to the teacher.

Comment: @WiktorZychla you are right :(

Answer (score 1):

If your access control implementation is done only on client-side it means that it will be relatively easy for an attacker (even for beginner one) to get access to the functionality you want to hide:

1. Since source code of the app is available, hacker can make changes in it and reveal all the hidden things or remove all the checks/condition you implemented.
2. Moreover, if all the security logic is located in client-side JS, then your back-end is not protected, so hacker may simply make calls to your API and do whatever he needs even without using front-end at all.

In conclusion, such approach is reasonable only for demo projects or proof of concept, but not for the applications available for public.